# Sums with index expressions instead of variables

Tags: summation

Often I replace $k$ with, say, $m-k^2$ in a sum, obtaining something like this:
$$\sum_{0\leq m-k^2\leq n} f(k)$$
Is there a way to input these without manually solving the inequalities?

Comment: maybe `Sum[f[k] Boole[0 <= m - k^2 <= n], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]`?

Comment: @kgir Is mathematica able to work with that, though?

Comment: Rene, it seems to work; please check if the answer i posted is what you had in mind.

Comment: @kglr No, what I mean is does that mess up Mathematica's ability to try to find a closed form?

Comment: When I tried `Sum[i^2 Boole[0 <= m - i^2 <= n], {i, 1, n}]`, it took some time but did give an output in closed form.

Comment: It was kind of kglr to answer you, but really, "does that mess up Mathematica's ability to try to find a closed form" is something you could have tried and answered yourself by running the snippet he supplied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sumF = Sum[f[k] Boole[#], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}] &;
sumF[m <= 100 - k^2 <= n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sumF[0 <= 100 - k^2 <= 50]
```

> f[-10] + f[-9] + f[-8] + f[8] + f[9] + f[10]

```
sumF[0 <= 100 - k^2 <= 50] /. f -> (#^2 &)
```

> 490

```
Sum[i^2 Boole[0 <= m - i^2 <= n], {i, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]